# Using own library with pyspark sc.parallelize on databricks hangs

Tags: pyspark, databricks

I have my own fairly simple python library that gets installed on a databricks cluster via the typical way (adding it as a pypi package in the cluster's libraries section).

Everything runs as expected on the cluster. Now I want to parallelize it.

This works:

```py
def run_example(x):
    import pandas as pd
    print(pd.__version__)
    return x

sc.parallelize([1,2,3]).map(lambda x: run_example(x)).collect()
```

Output:

```py
Out[86]: [1, 2, 3]
```

However, trying to call a function of my library in the `run_example` results in the job hanging. Trying to import my module also results in hanging. I.e., this does not work:

```py
def run_example(x):
    import my_package
    import pandas as pd
    print(pd.__version__)
    return x
```

By hanging, I mean the attached image. There's no discernible error in the spark logs.

[image: function hangs]

Comment: if possible please post your library functions as well here for better understand

Comment: I'm using Databricks runtime version 11.3 LTS, so things like pandas are already installed. No extra libraries are installed except `my_package` which I wouldn't be able to post here. But it's a typical python package that consists of dependencies like pandas, numpy etc.